# Oreo textview auto multiple line abnormal

Tags: android, textview

This is my Code, it is normal before Android 8.0, but in Android 8.0, it's auto to multiple line in different location. Any one can know why ？

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lwz15.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="请将设备插上电源后，等待一段时间后，直到设备启动完成"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what is abnormal?

Comment: What is the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: the normal result before android 8.0 is that the first line should arrive at the right end of the screen. In android 8.0, the first line ends in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should set your text `android:gravity`. It will set the correct way for the current language of the device:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:gravity="start" 
    android:text="请将设备插上电源后，等待一段时间后，直到设备启动完成"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Could you check this at start of your app? `Log.v( LOG_TAG, "Locale: " + getResources().getConfiguration().locale );`

Comment: Locale: zh_CN this is the log

Comment: Thanks for your help， I have resolved this problem with a weird solution. I use the edittext instead of the textview, and set edittext as follows: android:editable="false"  android:background="@null".  This can help me, but I don't know why.

Comment: By the way, this is not a bug of android 8.0. It only happens in XiaoMi Mix Phone.